# Drawing Polygon : unable to find error

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I made a program to draw Polygon but the Polygon is not showing up. I am trying to fix my code.

```
public static class Polygon extends JPanel {

    public Polygon() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics p)
    {
        super.paintComponent(p);
        int[] list1 = {100,50,150,200};  
        int[] list2 = {50,100,200,150};
        int n = 3;

        drawAPolygon(list1,list2,n);
    }

    public void drawAPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoints){
        Graphics p = getGraphics();
        p.setColor(Color.yellow);
        p.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getGraphics()` method doesn't work for you. But you can just pass your `Graphics` as parameter.

```
 public static class Polygon extends JPanel {

            public Polygon() {
                setBackground(Color.black);
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics p)
            {
                super.paintComponent(p);
                int[] list1 = {100,50,150,200};  
                int[] list2 = {50,100,200,150};
                int n = 3;
                drawAPolygon(p,list1,list2,n);
            }

            public void drawAPolygon(Graphics p, int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoints){
                p.setColor(Color.yellow);
                p.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints);
            }       
        }
```

Comment: I tried  Graphics g = getGraphics(); inside the method but that does not work .Is there any way i can initialize Graphics inside the method.

Comment: When you call `getGraphics()` method any change will be temporary and it will be lost at next repainting. So you need to initialize it at `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and only then work with it in your method. There no ways to initialize `Graphics` inside `drawAPolygon`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have a static class, change that first, then try the suggestions below.

I would do everything in the paintComponent method. This code works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Polygon extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics p)
    {
        super.paintComponent(p);

        int[] list1 = {100,50,150,200};  
        int[] list2 = {50,100,200,150};
        int n = 3;

        p.setColor(Color.yellow);
        p.drawPolygon(list1, list2, n);
    }    
}
```

Here is a runner class with a main method so you can test it out:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawPolygon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon panel = new Polygon();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

That color doesn't show up well, maybe there is a method to make it thicker?

Comment: Thats correct but I want to make it by making a method